# Difference between fabrication and modification

Tags: security, data

I came across one of the books related to **information security** where i saw these two terms, **fabrication** and **modification** of data.

I can't figure out how they are different?

What is the difference between **fabrication** and **modification** of data?

Could anyone please explain me these, in very simple terms?

Update:

**fabrication**: An unauthorized party inserts counterfeit objects into the system and basically attacks the authenticity of the system.

**modification**:  An unauthorized party modifies the assets of the system and basically attacks the integrity of the system.

Comment: can you post a link what's fabrication do you mean? thanks

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander is it enough?

Comment: Just look up the words in a dictionary. With fabrication, the attacker creates data that is to fool the system from scratch. That data does not exist, the attacker produces it. With modification, originally legitimate data is intercepted and changed before it reaches the validating system in order to trick that system into doing something different than the original sender intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you break into a billing system and want to create havoc:

**Fabrication** would, for example mean, you make up a non-existant supplier with made up contracts and regularily payments to your own account.

**Modification** would mean in the same context you pick an existing supplier with existing valid contracts and existing, valid payments but change his account number to yours.

Comment: is this merely your opinion or you can back it up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In **fabrication**, you put in a new counterfeit item into the data set. In **modification**, you just take an existing item from the data set and change it.

As you already pointed out, the former compromises the authenticity of your data. Let's use an analogy... Imagine you record your daily expenses. Someone gets a hold of it. Inserting a new bogus expense into your 12-Aug-2016 record is data fabrication. That day's record is no longer authentic.

The latter on the other hand, compromises data integrity. Extending the previous analogy... if that someone just takes an existing expense, say what you spent for lunch, from 12-Aug-2016 and doubles the amount, then that's data modification. The record will still look authentic. But the total expense would be corrupted.